# My virtual hosts file for my subdomain is not being picked up

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

So I have a website running on a lamp stack on Ubuntu.

I have two vhosts files...

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.co.uk
        ServerAdmin admin@example.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-a_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-a_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And moodle.example.co.uk.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName moodle.example.co.uk
        ServerAdmin admin@example.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/moodle.example.co.uk/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-b_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-b_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to www.example.co.uk then I see the home page. Exactly as expected.

However if I go to moodle.example.co.uk I still see the homepage not the page stored in the DocumentRoot specified.

If I add a ServerAlias directive to the Moodle conf then it works fine.

Why does the ServerName directive not work?

**EDIT:** an update. If i disable ALL virtual hosts then my website is still served. this seems like very odd behaviour.

The access is logged in other_vhosts_access.log but I cannot find anything that should lead to this behaviour.

With no vhosts defined should the site just give a connection refused error?

Comment: Does this system only have two virtual hosts? Or is your post about these two virtual hosts?

Comment: Currently only 2 as far as I am aware (in sites-enabled/) I usually have more but I am cutting down to fewer to troubleshoot before restoring the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

From Apache 2.4 documentation (may help):

> When a request arrives, the server will find the best (most specific)
>   matching  argument based on the IP address and port used
>   by the request. If there is more than one virtual host containing this
>   best-match address and port combination, Apache will further compare
>   the ServerName and ServerAlias directives to the server name present
>   in the request.
>
> If you omit the ServerName directive from any name-based virtual host,
>   the server will default to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)
>   derived from the system hostname. This implicitly set server name can
>   lead to counter-intuitive virtual host matching and is discouraged.

The following is most interesting: "If you omit the ServerName directive from **any name-based virtual host**, the server will default to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) derived from the system hostname"

Comment: But I do have ServerName in both virtual hosts files. Or is there a hidden one I don't know about?

Comment: It is possible you could. Execute in /etc/apache2 `egrep -R 'Server(Name|Aliaas)' *` to find all occurrences. Do you have browser cache completely disabled?